# How to redifine (via ENVIRON package) the "pmatrix" environment?

Tags: latex

I want to redefine the "pmatrix" environment provided by AMSMATH package (and changed by MATHTOOLS package) for adding good-looking delims. The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amstools,environ}
\RenewEnviron{pmatrix}{\PARENS{\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}}}
```

"PARENS" command is provided by MTPRO2 package to get curved left/right parensis. But it not work. Further, there's a star-ed version pmathix* envrionment (with a optional arg l/c/r), I don't have any idea either. The code I can give is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amstools,environ}
\RenewEnviron{pmatrix*}[1][c]{\PARENS{\begin{matrix*}[c]\BODY\end{matrix*}}}
```

I mail to ENVIRON package's author Will Robertson (wspr81[at]gmail[dot]com) but no reply. He maybe been seen here usually. So I logged in and posted.

Comment: You can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.  Will is seen there often as well as many other helpful people.  They might be interested in the specific outcome; did it compile and produce something you didn't want, or did it give an error?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: thanks for your info! I will go to the group. And for above codes, it produce an error.